# How to automate this custom gene expression microarray chip?

Tags: gene-expression, mrna, microarray

I have 16 gene sequences that I am interested in their detection in clinical samples. I already measured their RNA levels by using RT-qPCR technique and their benefit has already been proven to help in diagnosis of clinical cases. Now I want to take this gene expression profiling into another level of automation. The first thing came to my mind is the microrray chips. I don't have much experience in micrarrary, I want to have a custom chip containing these 16 genes in question. These are 13 target human genes and 3 reference genes (housekeeping genes) for normalization.

**Question**
- is it possible to have this custom chip?
- How can I get such a custom microarray chip?
- What is needed to automate this process at a production level?